# Can't add multiple lines of components into variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I want to save the content in a variable depending on the result of an if statement. But when I add multiple lines it doesn't work.

```
let content = null
if(this.props.group.name != null){
  content = <Text>Just this line works</Text>
              <Text>This doesn't work</Text>
}
```

I can't find out what to do. I can't add + at the end of the line like in Javascript.

Comment: Can't you just add it next to each other? Like this - `content = <Text>Just this line works</Text> <Text>This doesn't work</Text>`

Comment: Not when it is more content. This is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components need to be wrapped in a parent containing component, unless you create it as an array with keys.

```
// this would work because it's wrapped inside parentheses and has a parent component
content = (
          <View>
            <Text>Just this line works</Text>
            <Text>This doesn't work</Text>
          </View>
          )

// this works because the components are an array
content = [
           <Text key="1">Just this line works</Text>,
           <Text key="2">This doesn't work</Text>
          ]
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I tried the parentheses but I didn't know you also needed to wrap it.

Comment: @SinanSamet glad I could help!